# Creating Map From Changelog With Path in Slice of Strings (Maybe append to map!?)

Tags: go

I have a slice of changes that looks like this:

```
type Change struct {
    Type string      // The type of change detected; can be one of create, update or delete
    Path []string    // The path of the detected change; will contain any field name or array index that was part of the traversal
    From interface{} // The original value that was present in the "from" structure
    To   interface{} // The new value that was detected as a change in the "to" structure
}
```

I'm trying to take this and create a new `map[string]interface{}` from this.

I realized looping through path I'd need to build upon the prior path but I'm unsure how to do this. E.g. Path with this: `{"one": {"two": {"three": "value"}}}` would have `[]string{"one", "two", "three"}`

Right now I have this code:

```
for _, change := range changeLog {

    for i, _ := range change.Path {
        changeMap[change.Path[i]] = make(map[string]interface{})
    

        if i == len(change.Path)-1 {
            if castMap, ok := change.To.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
                changeMap[p] = castMap
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But this doesn't account for the parents hence the result is a flat structure. How do I achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: If I understand right, you would like to create a map, that is a tree structure, with every leaf is the `To` interface? If yes then there is a problem if you have 2 paths like (a,b) and (a,b,c) because then your `changeMap["a"]["b"]` should be a `map[string]interface{}` to hold the next path to `"c"`, but it should also hold the `("a","b")`'s path `To` interface too, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transverse your slice of Change to a tree struct based on maps, you should use some node struct to hold the tree data, because a variable cannot hold a map and an interface (the To value) at the same time. I make this sample that works and build you a tree based on your changelog slice.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Change struct {
    Type string      // The type of change detected; can be one of create, update or delete
    Path []string    // The path of the detected change; will contain any field name or array index that was part of the traversal
    From interface{} // The original value that was present in the "from" structure
    To   interface{} // The new value that was detected as a change in the "to" structure
}

type Node struct {
    Children map[string]*Node
    To       interface{}
}

//Helper for printing the tree
func (n Node) Print(ident int) {
    id := strings.Repeat(" ", ident)
    fmt.Println(id+"To:", n.To)
    for key, value := range n.Children {
        fmt.Println(id + "[" + key + "]")
        value.Print(ident + 2)
    }
}

func main() {
    changeLog := make([]Change, 0)
    changeLog = append(changeLog, Change{
        Type: "update",
        Path: []string{"a", "b"},
        From: 1,
        To:   2,
    })
    changeLog = append(changeLog, Change{
        Type: "update",
        Path: []string{"a", "c"},
        From: 3,
        To:   4,
    })

    var node *Node
    root := &Node{
        Children: make(map[string]*Node),
        To:       nil,
    }
    for _, change := range changeLog {
        node = root
        for _, p := range change.Path {
            if _, found := node.Children[p]; !found {
                node.Children[p] = &Node{
                    Children: make(map[string]*Node),
                    To:       nil,
                }
            }
            node = node.Children[p]
        }
        node.To = change.To
    }
    //Note: if you try to get a non-exist path this way, the following will panic!
    //You should make a func to get the value of a path or get nil back if path not exists.
    fmt.Println(root.Children["a"].Children["b"].To)
    fmt.Println(root.Children["a"].Children["c"].To)
    root.Print(0)
}
```

[Try it on goplay.space](https://goplay.space/#JcPCbASzUqQ)

Output:

```
To: <nil>
[a]
  To: <nil>
  [b]
    To: 2
  [c]
    To: 4
```